# jQuery Waypoints won't trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-waypoints

I'm trying to use jQuery Waypoints in a website I'm building, but can't get it to trigger at all. Here's my code:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/waypoints.min.js"></script>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#div-a').waypoint(function() {
                console.log("waypoint a reached");
            });
            $('#div-b').waypoint(function() {
                console.log("waypoint b reached");
            });
        });
</script>
```

I've tried this with and without `$(document).ready(function(){`. Here's my CSS:

```
#div-a {
    height: 1000px;
    background-color:#EAEAEA; 
}
#div-b {
    height: 1000px;
    background-color:#D8D5E2; 
}
```

the divs are filled with placeholder text. The divs are surrounded by a container div with this css:

```
#container {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#8DA7CD;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Thank you. All of this is up live at http://wilsonbiggs.com/sandy/

Comment: Can you wrap it in the document ready again on your web page, just so I can look at debugging...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [**context**](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/#get-started) param this will say to waypoint where is your element scrolled (Search for $('#example-context') to see the context example)

```
$('#div-a').waypoint(function() {
                console.log("waypoint a reached");
            },{context:"#container"});
$('#div-b').waypoint(function() {
                console.log("waypoint b reached");
            },{context:"#container"});
```

I added an extra div to you page to test it and it's calling the messaged for each waypoint
like this:

```
<div id="div-a"></div>
<div id="div-b"></div>
<div id="div-c"></div>
```

Comment: Worked! Thank you, I didn´t know I had to do that. (:

Comment: You saved me! I had to add 'body' for it to work, 'window' isn't enough so it seems